# How to address R/Adehabitat error in count.points(locs, maps) : "the cellsize should be the same in x and y directions

Tags: r, adehabitathr

I am new to **R** and this is the first time I am trying to use `AdehabitatHS` for exploratory niche analysis.

I am trying to compute utilization weight of pixels in the `SpatialPixelDataset` "maps" based on species locations "Locs" using function

```
cp <- count.points(locs, maps),
```

and I get stuck, due to the

> "Error in count.points(locs, maps) : the cellsize should be the same in x and y directions".

Both the `SpatialPixelDataframe` and the `SpatialPointDataframe` were projected in UTM Zone 38 N. The medatadata of all rasters contains the same extent information as follows:

```
"columns     : 2894
rows        : 2854
ref. system : utm-38n
ref. units  : m
unit dist.  : 1.0000000
min. X      : 357340.6770191
max. X      : 654449.8385381
min. Y      : 4289927.4120989
max. Y      : 4582930.0142086
pos'n error : unknown
resolution  : 102.6638412"
```

Also, not sure if this is relevant to this issue, but the set of layers were built using `ArcGIS` and worked fine in `Maxent`, and `Biomapper`.

I would appreciate if anyone could give me a hint on how to resolve this issue.